# How to perform SUM, MINUS & DIVIDE in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a following query which is giving me Opening_HC/Attrition/Moved/Addition:

```
select(select SUM(Opening_HC) from(
(select count(emp_id) as Opening_HC from hcdata where status = 

"Active" and DOJ <='2014-11-02' and sub_department='Sub_dep_07' and 

production_support='prod_sup-02')
UNION ALL
(select count(emp_id) as Opening_HC from hcdata where status = "Moved" 

and DOJ <='2014-11-02' and inactive_date >= '2014-11-02' and 

sub_department='Sub_dep_07' and production_support='prod_sup-02')
UNION ALL
(select count(emp_id) as Opening_HC from hcdata where status = 

"Attrition" and DOJ <='2014-11-02' and inactive_date >= '2014-11-02' 

and sub_department='Sub_dep_07' and production_support='prod_sup-

02'))t1) as Opening_HC, (select count(emp_id) from hcdata where 

sub_department='Sub_dep_07' and production_support='prod_sup-02' and 

status='Attrite'and inactive_date between '2014-11-02' and  '2014-11-

08') as Attrition, (select count(emp_id) from hcdata where 

sub_department='Sub_dep_07' and production_support='prod_sup-02' and 

status='Moved' and inactive_date between '2014-11-02' and  '2014-11-

08') as Moved,(select count(emp_id) from hcdata where 

sub_department='Sub_dep_07' and production_support='prod_sup-02' and 

sub_department = 'Sub_dep_07' and   DOJ between '2014-11-02' and  

'2014-11-08') as Addition
```

Now what i am looking for is Closing_HC, Entity_Attrition% & Process_Attrition%

Calculation should be:

Closing_HC = Opening_HC + Addition - Attrition - Moved

Entity_Attrition% = Attrition/((Opening_HC + Closing_HC)/2)

Process_Attrition% = (Attrition + Moved)/((Opening_HC + Closing_HC)/2)

Comment: Formatting nicely done.

Comment: [Follow this link it will definitely help you](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3ups99)

Comment: @Pankaj-Link not working in Office :(

Comment: @juergend Sarcasm works soo well on the internet ;-)

Comment: I did't get you guys

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in thinking that all of `t1`/`Opening_HC` can be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(emp_id) Opening_HC
  FROM hcdata
 WHERE (status = 'Active')
    OR (status IN('Moved','Attrition') AND inactive_date >= '2014-11-02') 
   AND DOJ <= '2014-11-02' 
   AND sub_department = 'Sub_dep_07' 
   AND production_support = 'prod_sup-02'
```

?

AND does `status` really ever equal 'Attrite'?

Comment: @Strawberry- It's giving me incorrect output, after running my query table is coming like: Opening_HC -- Attrition -- Moved -- Addition, these are the headers which is coming & matching too with data